# Latex code in knitr script?

Tags: knitr

I'm using `knitr` to rewrite some documents originally written in latex.
Here is the preamble of the `knitr`

```
---
title: "Blabla"
date: "May 2, 2017"
bibliography: allpapers.bib
output:
  word_document:
    fig_caption: true
    reference_docx: "Empty.docx"
---
```

Now, in the original latex version I was using this:

```
\newcommand{\myinput}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand\normalsize{\small}% Specify your font modification
  \input{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
\begin{centering}
\myinput{table1.txt}
\end{centering}
```

The `table1.txt` is a prefomated latex table. I would like to include 
these tables in the ``knitr`document without rewriting them from scratch, by just including`table1.txt`in the`knitr`, somehow. How can this be done?

PS the `table1.txt` files have the form:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllr}
  \hline
 & sdsd & dfdf & sdsd \\ 
  \hline
1 & sdsd & sdsd & -1.04 \\ 

   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{blabl.} 
\label{table1}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include LaTeX code verbatim in RMarkdown source files, and when you output to a format that uses LaTeX (i.e., pdf), the LaTeX is treated exactly as you expect.

However, if you're exporting to a non-LaTeX format, such as a word doc or html, then the exporter will just ignore the LaTeX.

```
---
title: "Test"
---

This is a test. Here's some \LaTeX{}:

\newcommand{\myinput}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand\normalsize{\small}% Specify your font modification
  \input{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
\begin{centering}
\myinput{table1.txt}
\end{centering}

Now I'm done.
```

[image]